# How to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in SonarQube?

Tags: angular, cors, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

My setup is SonarQube (localhost:9000) and Angular 4 instance (localhost:4200). I can successfully perform a GET request with Angular from SonarQube without authorization. However, **after adding http basic auth headers**, the same **request fails with `"Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405."`**

This is my GET request:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('admin:admin'));
this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/components/search?qualifiers=DIR', { headers: headers }, )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Chrome output:

[image]

I have tried adding CorsFilter to web/WEB-INF/web.xml according to tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html), but it did not change the response headers. How to correctly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing in SonarQube?

Comment: I tried to do something similar but as far as I know the Sonar team refuse to add support for CORS. No idea, why they developed a web api in the first place when they don't allow ajax calls to it.